# Best practice for re-installing APK via shell command?

Tags: android, shell

I have a curated Android device that downloads an updated APK from a private server and will re-install the app using a shell command, "pm install -f -r "

The command works, but when the re-install happens, the device shows a popup, saying the app stopped (like it crashed).

Is there a safe way to re-install the app?

Should I be stopping the app first, re-installing then re-starting it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know is there a problem with this "force close" dialog.

You can try the following:

1) Stop app first, after that re-install it
use:

```
adb shell am kill [options] <PACKAGE>
```

or on Honeycomb:

```
adb shell am force-stop <PACKAGE>
```

where  is the package name for you application.

2) I always do like that:
uninstall application:

```
adb uninstall <PACKAGE>
```

and install it again:

```
adb install <PATH TO APK>
```

The problem with second solution is that all data cached in Android/data will be removed

Hope it helps.

Comment: I need to keep the stored data, so un-install is not applicable. I tried the kill command and it wasn't doing anything, so I used force-stop instead, which works, without any popups.